# Bash -c argument passing to find

Tags: bash, find, arguments

This command works

```
find . -name \*.txt -print
```

and outputs two filenames

This command works

```
bash -c 'echo . $0 $1 -print' "-name" "\*.txt"
```

and outputs this result:

> . -name *.txt -print

But this command

```
bash -c 'find . $0 $1 -print' "-name" "\*.txt"
```

does not give an error but does not output anything either.

Can anyone tell me what is happening here?

Comment: Are you sure there are `*.txt` files to print? What does `find . -name \*.txt -print` print?

Comment: So the issue I see is that using bash -c gives 2 opportunities for the bash processor to expand `*.txt`. I'm not sure what the fix is, though

Comment: Please take a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to use `"\*.txt"` to forestall glob-expansion so that the `find` command sees `*.txt` instead of e.g. `foo.txt`.

However, what it ends up seeing is `\*.txt`. No files match that pattern, so you see no output.

To make `find` see `*.txt` as its 3rd argument, you could do this:

```
bash -c 'find . $0 "$1" -print' "-name" "*.txt"
```

Edit: Are you really getting `. -name *.txt -print` as the output of the first command where you replaced `find` with `echo`? When I run that command, I get `. -name \*.txt -print`.

Comment: The difference in `echo` output might be from `echo` trying to interpret escapes itself. Different versions of `echo` are wildly inconsistent about this sort of thing.

Comment: My mistake. The echo cmd does in fact output \*.txt

Answer (score 0):

Well the suggestions from francesco work. But I am still confused by the behaviour here.
We know that putting unquoted wild cards in a find command will usually result in an error. To wit:

```
find . -name *.txt -print
```

> find: paths must precede expression: `HowTo-Word-Split.txt' find:
>   possible unquoted pattern after predicate`-name'?

However putting the wild card in single quotes (or escaping it if it is only 1 char) will work like so:

```
find . -name \*.txt -print
```

which gives this output (on two separate lines)

```
> ./HowTo-Word-Split.txt    
> ./bash-parms.txt
```

So in the bash -c version what I was thinking was this:

```
bash -c 'find . $0 $1 -print' "-name" "*.txt"
```

would result in the *.txt being expanded even before being passed in to the cmd string,
and using single quotes around it would result in trying to execute (after the arg substitution and the -c taking effect)

```
find . -name *.txt -print
```

which as I just demonstrated does not work.

However there seems to be some sort of magic associated with the -c switch as demonstrated by setting -x at the bash prompt, like so:

```
$ set -x
$ bash -c ' find . $0 "$1" -print' "-name" "*.txt"

+ bash -c ' find . $0 "$1" -print' -name '*.txt'
./HowTo-Word-Split.txt
./bash-parms.txt
```

Note that even though I used double quotes in the -c line, bash actually executed the find with single quotes put around the argument, thus making find work.

Problem solved. :)!